# Ember.js didInsertElement issue on application load

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having a context issue within Ember.js and I'm not sure the way to handle it. The newrecord and editrecord views use didInsertElement to load external libraries. However, when I start my application the user has access to their records that have new messages, but when I click on these it's acting as if the libraries haven't loaded (which they probably havent').

Below are the routes that I have....

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('home', { path: '/'}); //<-- the links exist here here
    this.resource('form', { path: '/forms:form_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('editrecord', {path: '/:record_id/editrecord'}); //<-- the links go to here
    });
    this.resource('newrecord', { path: '/forms:form_id/newrecord' });
```

The application starts on the home route where the links to the records (which takes you to editrecord) are present. When I go from the initial page load to these links the libraries don't appear to be loaded.

However, if I navigate to the form route and then click on the links to the records the libraries are loaded and I'm not getting any errors.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the views and the didInsertElement calls too?

Comment: Can you post more info (like how/where you added the didInsertElement calls? I'm running into a similar issue myself where didInsertElement on the applicationRoute never gets triggered.

Comment: I added the didInsertElement calls at the beginning of the view.

For example...

    App.FormView = Ember.View.extend({
        
        didInsertElement: function() {

        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Probably you also forget to add the colon in the record_id

`this.resource('editrecord', {path: '/:record_id/editrecord'});`

Comment: this is just a typo and has been fixed. The routes work fine and the issue is strictly related to the didInsertElement and the external library.